# How do I limit a git pre-commit hook to only act on files with certain extensions?

Tags: git, file-type, pre-commit-hook

I have the following Git pre-commit hook at ~/.git-templates/hooks/pre-commit .  It is designed to remove unnecessary white space from the end of each line in a file ...

```
# A git hook script to find and fix trailing whitespace in your commits. Bypass
# it with the --no-verify option to git-commit.

# detect platform
platform="win"
uname_result=`uname`
if [[ "$uname_result" == "Linux" ]]; then
  platform="linux"
elif [[ "$uname_result" == "Darwin" ]]; then
  platform="mac"
fi

# change IFS to ignore filename's space in |for|
IFS="
"

# remove trailing whitespace in modified lines
for line in `git diff --check --cached | sed '/^[+-]/d'` ; do
  # get file name
  if [[ "$platform" == "mac" ]]; then
    file="`echo $line | sed -E 's/:[0-9]+: .*//'`"
    line_number="`echo $line | sed -E 's/.*:([0-9]+).*/\1/'`"
  else
    file="`echo $line | sed -r 's/:[0-9]+: .*//'`"
    line_number="`echo $line | sed -r 's/.*:([0-9]+).*/\1/'`"
  fi

  # since $file in working directory isn't always equal to $file in index,
  # we backup it; thereby we can add our whitespace fixes without accidently
  # adding unstaged changes
  backup_file="${file}.working_directory_backup"
  cat "$file" > "$backup_file"
  git checkout -- "$file" # discard unstaged changes in working directory

  # remove trailing whitespace in $file (modified lines only)
  if [[ "$platform" == "win" ]]; then
    # in windows, `sed -i` adds ready-only attribute to $file (I don't kown why), so we use temp file instead
    sed "${line_number}s/[[:space:]]*$//" "$file" > "${file}.bak"
    mv -f "${file}.bak" "$file"
  elif [[ "$platform" == "mac" ]]; then
    sed -i "" "${line_number}s/[[:space:]]*$//" "$file"
  else
    sed -i "${line_number}s/[[:space:]]*$//" "$file"
  fi
  git add "$file" # to index, so our whitespace changes will be committed

  # restore unstaged changes in $file from its working directory backup, fixing
  # whitespace that we fixed above
  sed "${line_number}s/[[:space:]]*$//" "$backup_file" > "$file"
  rm "$backup_file"

  [[ "$platform" == "mac" ]] || e_option="-e" # mac does not understand -e
  echo $e_option "Removed trailing whitespace in \033[31m$file\033[0m:$line_number"
done

echo

# credits:
# https://github.com/philz/snippets/blob/master/pre-commit-remove-trailing-whitespace.sh
# https://github.com/imoldman/config/blob/master/pre-commit.git.sh

# If there still are whitespace errors, print the offending file names and fail.
exec git diff-index --check --cached $against --

# Now we can commit
exit
```

Issue is, I would only like the pre-commit hook to apply to files of certain extensions.  What do I need to do to limit the action to only extensions that I choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_commit) takes no parameters.

But, as in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tregoning/3401530), you can list files about to be committed with [`git diff-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index).

Specifically, using the [`--diff-filter` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index#Documentation/git-diff-index.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203):

```
git diff-index --name-only --cached --diff-filter = ACMRTX
```

Example:

```
# Show files about to be commited that do not match filters in .jshintignore and are js files 
for FILE in ` git diff-index --name-only --cached --diff-filter = ACMRTX $ {against} - |  grep -v -f .jshintignore |  grep \.  js $ -i ` ;  do 
  jshint $ {FILE} >> / dev / null 
  EXIT_CODE = ` expr $ {EXIT_CODE} + $?  ` 
done 

if [[ $ {EXIT_CODE} -ne 0]] ;  then 
  echo " " 
  echo " ----------------------------------------------- " 
  echo " | * * * EPICFAIL * * * | " 
  ...
fi

exit $ (( $ {EXIT_CODE} ))
```

Comment: So then in your example above, are the files to which you're applying your changes before the commit the ones ending with the extensions ".jshintignore" and ".js"?

Comment: @Dave In this example, yes.